# Designview of MainContainer.java won't start

Tags: rapidclipse

Today I downloaded and installed the brand new Rapidclipse X framework. After installing I created a new workspace and a new project with Menubar-Template. Now when I open the MainContainer.java, the Designview stays blank and in the Progress-View, the "Starting virtual machine"-process hangs.
I already checked ports of virtual servers, installed local Tomcat and so on, nothing worked. Anyone here with the same issue or any help?

Answer (score 0):

**If you will migrate/upgrade from Rapidclipse 4 to Rapidclipse X**

You have to redesign the whole User Interface fresh. Because **Rapidclipse 4 uses Vaadin 8 that has "GWT components"** and  **Rapidclipse X uses Vaadin 14 that has the "web Components"**.

- Fresh start by redesigning an existing Vaadin 8 application using
  Vaadin 14 tools.

[Upgrading from Vaadin 8](https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/guide/upgrading/v8)

> ***But for some reason, you want your application to be open in IE 11 and evergreen browsers, you should use Vaadin 8 because Vaadin 14+ is not supported by these two browsers.***